# How does sympy substitute when there are different powers of a term in an expression?

Tags: python, sympy

In the code below, I have an expression and I want to substitute some things in the expression.
when I try to substitue (sym.sin(x)*sym.cos(2*x)**3) with y, It doesn't substite it in the first try and it first substitutes sym.sin(x) * sym.cos(2*x)**2 with sym.symbols('delta').

I know that I can substitue (sym.sin(x)*sym.cos(2*x)**3)  with y first and do the other substitutions afterward (like in 2)

Is there a way to change the order of substitutions?
(I have also tried xreplace)

```
expr = (sym.sin(x)*sym.cos(2*x)**3) / (2*sym.sin(2*x)) + sym.sin(x) / x + sym.cos(x) / x**2
display(expr)

# 1
display(expr.subs({
    sym.sin(x): z,
    sym.cos(x): sym.symbols('alpha'),
    sym.sin(x) * sym.cos(2*x)**3: y,
    sym.sin(x) * sym.cos(2*x)**2: sym.symbols('delta')
}))

# 2
display(expr.subs({
    sym.sin(x) * sym.cos(2*x)**3: y
}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the order of substitution preserved when passing a dictionary, d, pass the d.items(). In your case you will get:

```py
>>> d = your substitution dictionary
>>> expr.subs(d.items())
alpha/x**2 + z*cos(2*x)**3/(2*sin(2*x)) + z/x
```

Comment: Note, too: `xreplace` is much more literal than `subs`. And subs has the `simultaneous=True` option that can be helpful. 

But using the `subs([(old1, new1), (old2, new2)...])` syntax will do the substitutions in order so you will know what to expect, e.g. `(x*y*z).subs([(x*y,3), (y*z,2)]) -> 3*z` because `y*z` is no longer present after the first replacement.